# What does the `&=` syntax do/mean in Julia?

Tags: julia

I saw a slide at last night's Julia Meetup in Cambridge that had the `&=` syntax on it. I've never seen this before. what does it mean and can anyone provide an quick example?

Comment: It was not clear to me at all given that when I searched the docs for `&=` the results are not that helpful, hence asking here. You can see what the search result returns here https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/search/?q=%26%3D

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the [docs](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/mathematical-operations/#Updating-operators-1), `&` is the Bitwise AND operator and `&=` is the Bitwise AND update operator.

Similar to how

```
x = 1
x += 3
x
```

Will yield `4`

Then

```
x &= y
x
```

Will yield the bitwise AND result of x and y

If you aren't familiar with the bitwise operator, it's worth doing a quick reading to familiarize yourself [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation).